# Xamarin to MAUI Conversion Publish not working iOs

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have converted my one application in Xamarin.Forms to Net MAUI (tried both dot net 7 and 8)

My Application publish successful in Xamarin.Forms for both Android and iOs

However in Dot Net Maui I am only able to compile for Android

I have followed the exact steps as defined on Microsoft Website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs) and I am able to run the application in debug mode on my iPhone

But when it comes to publish it would just get stuck on

`--skip-unresolved true  --notrimwarn --custom-data "LinkerOptionsFile=obj/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/custom-linker- options.txt" --verbose -b --disable-opt unusedtypechecks --enable-opt sealer --enable-serialization-discovery`

And then about 10-15 minutes later the following error

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1214,3): error : Messaging Exception: An error occurred while executing the operation and the connection could not be reestablished [B:\Projects\S ocialBean\SocialBean.App\SocialBean.App.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1214,3): error : ClientDis connectedException: The client build2787627876Donal has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/bu ild/1.11.0.2/execute-task/SocialBean.App/2d13ffe002fAOTCompile [B:\Projects\SocialBean\SocialBean.App\SocialBean.App.cs proj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1214,3): error :  [B:\Proj ects\SocialBean\SocialBean.App\SocialBean.App.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]`

I have tried clean and build.
I have tried Publish in VS2022

I have tried to publish via cmd
`dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="iPhone Distribution: Peach Software Solutions (Pty) ltd. (3PWMH82R6R)" -p:CodesignProvision="SocialBean Deploy"`

After another test, based on a comment by liqun Shen-Msft, it deploys in release mode, or at least get closer with the following error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/donaldjansen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/SocialBean.App/2d13ffef70bd6915ab8d382b7897e1ec3ab815ae362adda36248c0d874bad713/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/SocialBean.App.app' on the device 'Donald???s iPhone': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015.            0

Comment: Can the application deploy to the iphone in release mode using pair to mac?

Comment: Looks like it does deploy to the iphone when in release mode. just tried again and it worked, but publish still fails

Comment: Ok, I managed to deploy it once, looks like it creates the .ipa file but I get a new error, not sure if it will prevent me from uploading the ipa file which i am going to try now

Comment: Looks like I was able to upload the ipa file, so I have a work around for now

Comment: Great! Feel free to share your workaround here, that may help others with similar issues!

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is not the solution to the issue but it is a work around.

Select your distribution profile then select release mode, cpu must be on iPhone and then run it on your iPhone as you would when debugging.

When the Compile time out or cancels the operation then you can go to your archives on the mac, you will find the ipa file which you can upload.

It looks like everything succeeds as it should but it doesn't properly notify VS that it succeeded